# Use value from list as selector SCSS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm passing a list into a mixin to reduce the number of parameters I have to pass into my mixin. The mixin code can be seen below.

```
@mixin colorMedal($medalData) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    nth($medalData,2) 0%,
    nth($medalData,2) 50%,
    nth($medalData,1) 50.1%,
    nth($medalData,1) 100%
  );
  #{nth($medalData,0)} ~ .medal__ribbon--left {
    background: nth($medalData,3);
  }
  #{nth($medalData,0)} ~ .medal__ribbon--right {
    background: nth($medalData,4);
  }
}
```

The list that im passing looks something like this

```
$platinum: ".medal__platinum", $medal-platinum, $medal-platinum-dark,
  $medal-platinum-ribbon, $medal-platinum-ribbon-dark;
```

And the call of the mixin is :

```
@include colorMedal($platinum);
```

The code that seems to be causing a compile error is

`#{nth($medalData,0)}`

There must be a way to do this since you can pass in multiple values on their own. Is there a way to use a value from a list as a selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sass list starts at index 1 not 0

so change this from

```
#{nth($medalData,0)}
```

to

```
#{nth($medalData,1)}
```

you can debug the changes in codepen

https://codepen.io/srajagop/pen/wvBrzjO?editors=0102